# How to convert a single PHP upload image to multiple upload images

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a HTML form + PHP script to upload a single image keeping original name. I'd like to convert this script from single to multiple images upload keeping original name for every image.

This is my HTML code:

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile"/>
    <input type="text" name="imgdec">
    <button name="upload" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my PHP code:

```
    <?php


if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_filesize = 10485760;
$upload_path = 'uploads/';
$description = $_POST['imgdesc'];

$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
  die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename)) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO uploads (name, description) VALUES ($filename, $description)"; 
   mysql_query($query);

echo 'Your file upload was successful!';


} else {
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
}
}


?>
```

Comment: <input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a old post but some further explanation might be useful for someone trying to upload multiple files... Here is what you need to do:

- Input name must be be defined as an array i.e. name="inputName[]"
- Input element must have multiple="multiple" or just multiple
- In your PHP file use the syntax
  "$_FILES['inputName']['param'][index]"
- Make sure to look for empty file names and paths, the array might
  contain empty strings

here is a down and dirty example (showing just relevant code)

HTML:

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

PHP:

```
// Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps out!